# Comparison warning

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm doing an exercise to reverse the order of a vector. My program works, but I am getting a warning in the `for` loop I am executing below:

```
    void reverse (vector<int>& v){
        for(int i=0; i<v.size()/2; ++i){
            swap(v[i],v[v.size()-1-i]);
        }
    }
```

on the line of the `for` loop, I am getting the warning message "comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]". I am using Stroustrop's Programming Principles and Practice Using C++, and he uses basically that general format (without the / 2). Should I be writing this for-loop differently?

Comment: The result of `v.size()` is unsigned (`size_t` is unsigned). Therefore `i<v.size()/2` is a signed vs. unsigned comparison. Since your `i` will never be negative, you could define `i` as `unsigned int` or `uint32_t` or `size_t`.

Comment: Since `i` will never be negative, there is no real issue here. Your compiler is warning you that you might not be smart enough to understand the code that you've written, and should consider changing it to something that the compiler writer approves of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size function in a vector returns a size_t which is basically an unsigned int.  When you get a warning like that, check the variable types that you are being warned about.  One way of getting rid of the warning is to change the loop variable

```
for(size_t i=0; i<v.size()/2; ++i)
```

The problem is that still computes v.size()/2 every time.  So a better way would be

```
for(size_t i=0, stop=v.size()/2; i < stop; ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `size()` function in the `std::vector` class returns a [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) value, which is *always* defined as an `unsigned` type (though its bit-width may vary between platforms). This is generally true of all standard functions that return container, array or string size values (like `std::strlen()`), and the type is also used as the *actual* type for array indexes, and parameters to operators such as `new int[n]`.

To avoid the warning, simply declare your loop variable (`i`) as a `size_t` rather than a (signed) `int`:

```cpp
    void reverse (vector<int>& v){
        for(size_t i=0; i<v.size()/2; ++i){
            swap(v[i],v[v.size()-1-i]);
        }
    }
```